# html line ". {" is marked as an error in Eclipse when the html file is opened

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I have updated my Eclipse to 2021-03 with jdk1.8 and Tomcat 9. Now when I open a html the following css has an error on ". {" - identifier expected. When I close the file the error marker goes away.

```
 body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }
      . {
        max-width: 370px;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expecting a **classname** after `.`
If your purpose is to apply css to entire document then use

```
*{
        max-width: 370px;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
```

`.` is used for classes in CSS, hence it expects the `.` to be followed by a classname.
For more info visit [MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)
[image: MDN CSS Selectors]

Also for your convenience below is a screenshot of real-time log from vscode
[image: Real-time VSCode log]

As you can see it says identifier expected, this means that a classname is a must after `.` selector and when you do something like
`.class_name{}` you will see that the error is gone

Comment: Hi Uzair, are you able to explain why this has not been a problem for over four years and only after upgrading from Eclipse Mars to Eclipse 2021-03, from java 1.7 to java 1.8 and from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9? I did all of this in one fell swoop so do not know which caused the problem to be highlighted and all css and html has worked fine to date.

Comment: @Glyn You have overlooked the error by missing to upgrade Eclipse for years. Eclipse Mars is 6 years and 14 releases behind.

Comment: if my answer helped you in anyway pls accept the answer so that it helps others who come across similar problems

Comment: Hi Uzair, Sorry for the delay, I just wanted to do some testing first. I very much appreciate your help. Kind regards, Glyn

Comment: Anytime brother @Glyn